# How do i require 'csv' in ruby? Simply writing require 'csv' or "csv" is not working even though my Ruby is up to date

Tags: ruby, csv, rubygems, require

I am new to ruby and trying to use it's csv libary.

The first thing i tried was just to write a simple script:

```
require "csv"
average_money_spent = Array.new
CSV.foreach('customers.csv', converters: :numeric) do |row|
  average_money_spent << row[2] / row[1]
end
```

This gave the error message: Unclosed quoted field on line 1.
So then i tried the exact same thing but require 'csv'.
I got this error message: Unclosed quoted field on line 1.

I thought it may be to do with not having CSV gems installed on my ruby so i tried : 
$ gem install csv

This said it could not be installed:
    csv requires Ruby version >= 2.5.0dev.

But i tried to install this and checked .. it isn't the latest most stable version of Ruby, the version I have is.

Is there anything I am doing wrong in the way I require csv? Thanks so much for any help. I am new to coding and Ruby.

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with `require "csv"` but with your customers.csv file. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548637/csv-unquoted-fields-do-not-allow-r-or-n-line-2) or post your customers.csv if that would not help.

Comment: Right it means "unclosed quote field on line 1" *of the CSV*

Answer (score 2):

Please check and make sure your csvfile is in the correct format.