# CSV parsing returns "Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n" but can't find error in source file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, parsing, error-handling

I'm using the built-in CSV function in Ruby for my Rails app.  I am calling a URL (via HTTParty) parsing it, and attempting to save the results to my database.

The problem is, I'm getting the error `Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n` that indicates, normally, there is a problem with the input data, but in examining the data, I can't find any issues.

Here's how I retrieve data:

`response = HTTParty.get("http://" + "weather.com/ads.txt", limit: 100, follow_redirects: true, timeout: 10)`

(This data is publicly available at the url weather.com/ads.txt)

I then attempt to parse the data, with some regex applied to ignore everything after a `#`, ignore blank lines, etc.

`if response.code == 200 && !response.body.match(/<.*html>/)
active_policies = []`

```
CSV.parse(response.body, skip_blanks: true, skip_lines: /(^\s*#|^\s*$|^contact=|^CONTACT=|^subdomain=)/) do |row|
    begin
     #print out the individual ads.txt records 
     puts ""
     print row[0].downcase.strip + " " + row[1].strip + " " + 
     row[2].split("#").first.strip
            active_policies.push(
                publisher.policies.find_or_create_by(ad_partner: row[0].downcase.strip, external_seller_id: row[1].strip, seller_relationship: row[2].split("#").first.strip) do |policy|
                    policy.deactivated_at = nil
                end 
                )

                rescue => save
                #Add error event to the new sync status model
                puts "we are in the loop"
                puts save.message, row.inspect, save.backtrace
                    next
                end
                end
            #else
                #puts "Too many policies.  Skipping " + publisher.name
            #end
            #now we are going to run a check to see if we have any policies that are outdated, and if so, flag them as such.
            deactivated_policies = publisher.policies.where.not(id: active_policies.map(&:id)).where(deactivated_at: nil)
            deactivated_policies.update_all(deactivated_at: Time.now)
            deactivated_policies.each do |deactivated_policy|
                puts "Deactivating Policy for " + deactivated_policy.publisher.name
            end

         elsif response.code == 404 
            print 
            print response.code.to_s + " GET, "  + response.body.size.to_s + " body, "
            puts response.headers.size.to_s + " headers for " + publisher.name

         elsif response.code == 302
            print response.code.to_s + " GET, "  + publisher.name
         else 
            puts response.code.to_s +  " GET ads txt not found on " + publisher.name
         end

    publisher.update(last_scan: Time.now)

    rescue => ex
        puts ex.message, ex.backtrace, "error pulling #{publisher.name} ..." 
        #publisher.update_columns(active: "false")
    end
end`
```

**A couple of ideas I've had / results of investigation:**

1. I have tried going through this line by line, and I've identified that line 134 is what is breaking the scan.  I did this by doing a manual check like so: 
   `CSV.parse(response.body.lines[140..400].join("\n"), skip_blanks: true, skip_lines: /(^\s*#|^\s*$|^contact=|^CONTACT=|^subdomain=)/)` but this doesn't help me, because even if I identify line 134 as the offending line, I don't know how to detect or deal with it.

   2. I noticed that the source file (at weather.com/ads.txt) has unusual characters, but even forcing it to utf-8 via `response.body.force_encoding("UTF-8")` still throws the error.
   3. I tried adding `next` to the rescue block, so even if it finds an error, it will move on to the next row in the csv, but that doesn't happen - it just errors out and stops parsing - so I get the first 130~ entries, but not the remaining ones.
   4. Similar to page type, I'm not sure if the page type being HTML and not a text file is creating a problem here.

I would love to know how to detect and handle this error, so any thoughts here would be most welcome!

For reference, `#PBS` is apparently the line 134 that is giving me trouble in the source file, but I don't know if I fully trust that this is the issue.

```
#canada

google.com, pub-0942427266003794, DIRECT, f08c47fec0942fa0
indexexchange.com, 184315, DIRECT
indexexchange.com, 184601, DIRECT
indexexchange.com, 182960, DIRECT
openx.com, 539462051, DIRECT, 6a698e2ec38604c6

#spain

#PBS
google.com, pub-8750086020675820, DIRECT, f08c47fec0942fa0
google.com, pub-1072712229542583, DIRECT, f08c47fec0942fa0
appnexus.com, 3872, DIRECT
rubiconproject.com, 9778, DIRECT, 0bfd66d529a55807
openx.com, 539967419, DIRECT, 6a698e2ec38604c6
openx.com, 539726051, DIRECT, 6a698e2ec38604c6
google.com, pub-7442858011436823, DIRECT, f08c47fec0942fa0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are inconsistent line endings in that text, and the CSV parser is stumbling over them. A very quick fix is to remove all `\r` characters with:

```
response.body.gsub!("\r", '')
```

In case you are curious, one way to see the errant characters is the following code that writes the Ruby array notation of every character to a text file:

```
response = HTTParty.get("http://" + "weather.com/ads.txt", limit: 100, follow_redirects: true, timeout: 10)
characters = response.chars.inspect
output = File.open( "outputfile.txt","w" )
output << characters
output.close
```

Open up `outputfile.txt` and search for `\r` characters. I find just a couple of them at line endings, though all other lines are ended with `\n` alone.

Comment: the `response.body.gsub!("\r", '')` solved it! I'm curious, where is the location of outputfile.txt? apologies if that's a dumb question, but I have another issue that I suspect is the same problem - I'm getting the error `Illegal quoting in line 540.` for techradar.com/ads.txt, and I think there are hidden / errant characters present here too, just not line breaks

Comment: The other answer, by @bkimble, uses `tr()` rather than `gsub()`, which is probably a more efficient choice for a single character removal like this. The `outputfile.txt` would be created by that code in the Rails project root directory. The line number 540 that you are a seeing may be a little misleading, because some of the lines are being skipped before CSV assigns line numbers. The illegal quoting is actually on line 580: `tremorhub.com, q017o-78mlk, RESELLER, 1a4e959a1b50034a # Premium video demand aka "Telaria" #`

Comment: ok I'll make the changes to use `tr()` - to avoid the "Telaria" issue, would I control for quotes via regex?

Comment: You could, I guess. You could also use `tr()` or `gsub()` to remove all quotation mark charters. Though either of these could be messy because quotation marks are also a legitimate delimiter in .csv files, just not used in this one. I notice that the quotes that are giving you trouble are in the text after the `#` that you are removing. But, you're removing it after CSV is parsing the lines. Consider removing it beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like whats happening is that the input file's lines are terminated with \n, except for lines 134 and 135, which are terminated with \r\n. CSV by default has its :row_sep set to :auto, which looks at the file to determine which separator is most appropriate, and it selected "\n". Those extra carriage returns make it think that you have a multi line field which is not encapsulated by quotes.

You can fix this by pre parsing the file before CSV gets to it, and removing the \r:

Change:

```
CSV.parse(response.body, skip_blanks: true, skip_lines: /(^\s*#|^\s*$|^contact=|^CONTACT=|^subdomain=)/) do |row|
```

to:

```
CSV.parse(response.body.tr("\r", ''), skip_blanks: true, skip_lines: /(^\s*#|^\s*$|^contact=|^CONTACT=|^subdomain=)/) do |row|
```